# DLL shared memory problems with different session, service and user session

Tags: windows, session, synchronization, shared

first, Thank you read this :)

I use DLL shared Memory and using interlocked~ functions. (Win 7)

DLL loaded by service exe and user app exe.

you know, service session is 0, user session is 1 so different.

if DLL's shared memory value changed by user app exe, not reflected service's DLL shared memory value.

is there a way to sync service and user app's DLL shared memory?

Comment: not using named file map. using dll's shared section.

Comment: DLL shared memory is a legacy feature.  You shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared sections don't work across session boundaries any more. Microsoft considered this a security problem and deliberately broke the feature, quite some time ago if memory serves. I believe each session now sees its own private copy of the section.

However memory mapped files (MMFs) work fine, and I use this in place of shared sections now. The only downer is that globally-available MMFs have to be created with high privilege, so I use a service to create the MMF.

Answer (score 1):

Try using global shared memory.  [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> Prefixing the file mapping object names with "Global\" allows
>   processes to communicate with each other even if they are in different
>   terminal server sessions.

Comment: I use code below 
#pragma data_seg ("/SECTION:.MYSEC,RWS")
int i = 0; 
char a[32]n = "hello world";
#pragma data_seg() 
Do you mean ".MYSEC" to "Global\.MYSEC" ?

Comment: You can't share across sessions using a dll shared data segment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the [credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also plays a role when sharing memory accross sessions.

> This requires that the first process must have the SeCreateGlobalPrivilege privilege