# Issue: Shared data in DLL

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++, dll

have a DLL which is shared between a windows service and a Test application. This DLL is loaded by both windows service and a Test application.

Service will create a thread and waits for specific message. This thread ID is stored in the shared memory of the DLL as shown below.

```
#pragma data_seg(".shared")
DWORD dwServiceThreadID = 0;
#pragma data_seg()

#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.shared,RWS")
```

and I am setting the thread ID of the service in method which is exposed by DLL as...

```
// Exposed method
void __stdcall HFDLL_setServiceThreadID(DWORD dwThreadID)
{
    dwServiceThreadID = dwThreadID;
}
```

I am using this `dwServiceThreadID` in the dll to post a message when an even occurs in the Test application.

```
if (dwServiceThreadID)
{
    PostThreadMessage(dwServiceThreadID, WM_KEY_PRESS, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Problem: When I try setting the service thread ID, using the exposed method `HFDLL_setServiceThreadID`, it is showing the ID properly. When I tried debugging the dll by attaching the Test Application, the variable `dwServiceThreadID` is showing 0.

Not getting what mistake I have made. Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DLL shared memory problems with different session, service and user session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827743/dll-shared-memory-problems-with-different-session-service-and-user-session)